# Am receiving this error in my elctron app (Uncaught ReferenceError: ipcRenderer is not defined) even after setting node integration to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, require, desktop-application

1. Am receiving this error in my elctron app (Uncaught ReferenceError: ipcRenderer is not defined) even after setting node integration to true

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: Below is my html code where the error emanated from

        <script>
            const electron = require('electron');
            const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

            const form = document.querySelector('form');
            form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

            function submitForm(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
                ipcRenderer.send('item:add', item);
            }
        </script>

Comment: "electron": "^14.0.0" am workin with input fields in HTML thats why its important

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to [edit] your question and put all the necessary code in there. Also, please use the `{}` button in the editor to format your code as code. That way it'll be much more readable. Thanks!